# When is the image of a regular map an algebraic variety?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a regular map of smooth connected algebraic varieties (say over an algebraically closed field). I know that the image $f(X)$ is only a constructible set, in general, but I am interested in conditions that ensure $f(X)$ being an algebraic variety.

**A precise question:** suppose the differential $df$ has a constant rank. Is $f(X)$ an algebraic variety (or a locally closed subvariety of $Y$)?

Comment: Even if the rank of $df$ is constant, the image may be only locally closed.  Let $X$ be the complement of the $s$-axis in the $(s,t)$-affine plane, $X=\{(s,t): t\neq 0\}$.  Let $Y$ be affine $3$-space with coordinates $(u,v,w)$.  Let $f$ be the function $f(s,t) = (s^2-1,s(s^2-1),s+t)$.  The image contains a dense open subset of the variety $\text{Zero}(v^2-u^2(u+1))$, namely the open complement of $C=\text{Zero}(u-(w^2-1),v-w(w^2-1))$.  However, the image also contains the points $f(-1,2)$ and $f(1,-2)$, and these are contained in $C$.

Comment: Locally closed is good. It is an algebraic variety!

Comment: You seem to be confused.  In my example, the image is *not* locally closed.

Comment: Yes, I am. You whammedd me with your first sentence!

Comment: The sentence should have been, "Even if the rank is constant, the image may be only constructible."

Comment: I presume this is one of the reasons for the importance of proper maps.

Comment: note that not only is the image closed if f is proper, e.g. f finite or X projective, but the image is open if f has finite fibers, by Grothendieck's version of ZMT.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am correcting the first sentence of the comment.

Even if the rank of $df$ is constant, the image may be only **constructible**.  Let $X$ be the complement of the $s$-axis in the $(s,t)$-affine plane, $X=\{(s,t): t\neq 0\}.$  Let $Y$ be the affine $3$-space with coordinates $(u,v,w).$  Let $f$ be the function $f(s,t)=(s^2-1,s(s^2-1),s+t)$.  The image of $f$ is the disjoint union of two locally closed subsets whose union is not locally closed.  The first locally closed set is $\text{Zero}(v^2-u^2(u+1))\setminus \text{Zero}(u-(w^2-1),v-w(w^2-1))$.  The second locally closed set is $\text{Zero}(u,v)$.  The union of these two locally closed sets is not locally closed.  It is only **constructible**.